# Node.js - variables scope and garbage collection

Tags: node.js, variables, this, local, winston

I am new to Node.js and JavaScript, so my question might be silly. I wanted to know if my code sample is correct in terms of variable lifetime. Here I am creating my own logger module which is wrapper for existing winston logger, but hides this dependency by exposing its own methods. I am creating local variable 'logger' inside the class constructor and then exposing some member methods to public using assignment to "this". This example works, but I have doubts if this is good way to implement this since requires local variable to stay in memory after constructor function finishes. I believe garbage collection should track this situation and do not destroy local variable since there are outside references, but is it a good practice to do so? Shall I use

```
this.logger = ...
```

instead of

```
let logger = ...
```

to keep whole variable exposed (which I want to avoid in order to hide implementation details)?
Code is:

```
var winston = require('winston');

class Logger {
    constructor () {

        let logger = winston.createLogger({
            level: 'debug',
            format: winston.format.json(),
            transports: [
                new winston.transports.Console(),
                new winston.transports.File({filename: 'results.log'})
            ]
        });

        this.error = logger.error;
        this.warn = logger.warn;
        this.info = logger.info;
        this.verbose = logger.verbose;
        this.debug = logger.debug;
    }
}

module.exports = new Logger;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing to worry about. `logger` variable should be destroyed right after `Logger#constructor` function exit, but destroying `logger` variable does not mean destroying an object which variable is reference on.

There one thing you must be sure - that `logger.error`, `logger.warn` and other logger methods are context independent. If it not - you must bind context like this

```
this.error = logger.error.bind(logger);
this.warn = logger.warn.bind(logger);
this.info = logger.info.bind(logger);
this.verbose = logger.verbose.bind(logger);
this.debug = logger.debug.bind(logger);
```

Comment: Thanks. But if `logger` is destroyed after constructor exits - how it works outside of the module then? I am using it like this in main app: `var logger = require('Logger'); logger.info('Test log message');`

Comment: Please, read about [closures in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)